# Using a function for Twilio autopilot response

Tags: node.js, twilio, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I'm making an autopilot assistant on Twilio and I have been having some trouble with the text-to-speech over the phone. For some reason, I have the default voice in the console set to Amazon Polly's "Joanna" voice but it keeps picking up/ making a call in a male voice that I haven't selected (I'm not even sure which one it is!).

While it sucks, I thought of a possible solution to this by just re-routing the responses to a Twilio Run-time function.

The problem is now is every time the assistant makes the call, it will just hangup once I answer the phone with "Hello". I have the conversation flow set up so it will say nothing until the person picking up the call will say "Hello" first, oppose to the assistant. I'm kind of new to this and haven't worked extensively with Node.js before, so I'm thinking maybe my function isn't correct.

Here's what I have:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;
  const response = new VoiceResponse();
  const hello = response.say({
  voice: 'Polly.Joanna'
 }, 'Testing to see if this works.');

responseObject = {
    "actions": [
     { 
       "say": hello
     },
     {
        "listen": true
     }
  ]
};

 callback(null, responseObject);
 };
```

The thought process behind this is just simply that instead of it being the male voice that keeps coming up, I've now specified 100% that is has to be the female "Joanna" voice. So the variable "hello" holds this information and uses it as the "say".

How do I get this function working so that it doesn't just hangup when I answer the phone and answers in "Joanna's" voice?

- Also note, nothing gets sent to the debugger too when this happens.

Comment: If anyone has the problem in the future, the problem was under Autopilot > Tasks > Stylesheets and then change the Amazon polly voice.